# Can't reinstall PostgreSQL after removal

Tags: windows, postgresql

When I try to uninstall PostgreSQl 12 it shows a message that says "info.datadirectory.kept". Then, when I try to reinstall Postgres the wizard shows another message that says "The database cluster did not started correctly". I can't do anything with Postgres: it doesn't start any Windows service, I can't connect to my localhost, it seems to don't install properly all the scripts and files... I don't know what to do, I've tried to reinstall several times and it doesn't work. It seems to be a problem from the database cluster initialization, I've searched some info about it but I can't use the `initdb` or `pg_ctl` commands instead.

I'm working on Windows 10 and trying to install PostgreSQL 12, but 11 didn't install correctly as well.

Comment: Probably this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901302/delete-old-postgresql-data-directory-in-win7

Comment: I've tried it but I can't find any postgres user